# È giusto dire "ti ho spedito un SMS"? Quali sono le alternative?

Tags: neologism

SMS sta per *[short message service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS)*, quindi non si riferisce ai messaggi ma a tutto il sistema; dire *ti ho spedito un SMS* non ha molto senso se uno espande e traduce l'abbreviazione. È un po' come dire "il numero PIN", ed è qualcosa di simile alla [RAS syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome).

È da considerarsi corretto, visto il largo uso? C'è qualche parere "ufficiale" dell'accademia della Crusca (che tra l'altro pure [usa questo termine](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/scritture-tachigrafiche)) a riguardo?

Quali sono le alternative? Tecnicamente uno dovrebbe dire *ti ho spedito un messaggio via SMS*, lungo, o *ti ho spedito un SM*, incomprensibile. *Messaggino* sembra molto colloquiale, mentre *messaggio* non chiarisce il mezzo utilizzato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In italiano, la parola “SMS” – a prescindere dal suo scioglimento come acronimo inglese – significa a tutti gli effetti “messaggino”. Quindi non è né giusto né sbagliato: è questo il significato con cui viene usata, come registrano, per esempio, lo Zingarelli e il Devoto-Oli (che danno entrambi come definizione proprio “messaggino”), come anche il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sms) che la fa più lunga ma conclude “Detto anche, fam., *messaggino*”. (Il [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/sms) è l'unico che riporta solo il significato come “sistema per invio...”, ma vedi sotto.)

E “messaggino” è a sua volta un lemma in ognuno di questi dizionari, e solo nel caso del [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/messaggino) ha come marca d'uso “fam(iliare)”, mentre negli altri è dato come termine normale. Per esempio, il Nuovo Devoto-Oli definisce, senza marche d'uso:

> Breve messaggio di testo inviato o ricevuto tramite telefono cellulare e visualizzato sul display dell'apparecchio: *mandare un messaggino di auguri*.

Il [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/messaggino) (con una piccola incoerenza rispetto a sopra) definisce: “SMS inviato spec. col telefono cellulare”.

Hai già segnalato che Vera Gheno, scrivendo per la Crusca, usa “SMS” senza problemi, cosa che succede anche in molti altri documenti della stessa accademia, e lo stesso fa Giuseppe Antonelli in un [articolo d'enciclopedia per la Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/il-linguaggio-degli-sms_(XXI-Secolo)/).

Quindi “SMS” e “messaggino” sono i due termini con cui si indica questo concetto in italiano contemporaneo.